# Skip ear packaging

Tags: java, maven

In the build pipeline I would like to skip ear packaging. This takes a lot of time, more than four minutes for each ear. And it only makes sense later in the pipeline if a release needs to be made.

I want to split the build pipeline in a number of discrete steps. First step is compile. For this first step I want to use `mvn install -DskipTests`. I want to use `install` because there are other dependencies e.g. jar depedencies that need to be satisfied in order to be able to do a complete compile.

How can I skip ear packaging when doing `mvn install -DskipTests`?

Comment: 4 Minutes? Sounds there is something wrong...How many modules do you have in the EAR file? What's the resulting size?

Comment: There are around 17 ear files average 40mb in size Almost all of this mb are in the lib directory - all the dependent jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option one:**

Change your module packaging to war/jar, then create another module and add original module as a dependency with packaging ear.

This way, you can build the war/jar module whenever you want, but when you need to release it - build the ear module.

**Option two:**

Change module packaging to war/jar. Create [Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) configuration that builds your ear file. Create profile "release" which binds Assembly plugin to lifecycle.

Result: without "release" profile enabled, ear will not be created.

Comment: Is it also an option to use compile goal and then to selectively create and install jar files where it is needed? To satisfy dependencies?

Comment: If you want to keep it automated - then not really. The only thing that can install dependencies is `install` phase. Therefore, whatever solution you choose, one of your modules has to actually create the `jar` in question and push it to repository during install phase. In my projects I'm usually sticking to option one, as it seems quite logical to me and does not require additional plugins. Just think about it, if you need your `jar` as a dependency, and then a `ear` as a build result, then basically you produce two artifacts. And both those artifacts have different reasons to be.

Comment: Do I need the Assembly plugin? What about putting all war, ear modules in release profile. When I want to release I just add the profile?

Comment: Assembly plugin is good to produce artifacts that are not installed into maven. Technically, you can install them too, but it becomes too hackish for my personal taste. Therefore, I usually use Assembly for stuff like continuous deployment, where I don't care for produced war to be in repository, I just want it to be built now. As about modules, if you create separate modules for wars/ears, then yes, you can enable them using profiles. However, again, if you don't care for wars/ears not being in maven repository - go with assembly plugin.

Comment: Another option is to use `pl` switch e.g. `mvn -pl '!:my_ear' install -DskipTests` but it is a bit cumbersome to list all my ear's that way.